# Calling back a crypted password?

Tags: php, hash

I hashed my password into the database using the crypt() function.

```
$cryptpass = crypt($user_pass);
```

Now when i try to login in with my password that is **"test"** it wont work.
Here is the PHP from login

```
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$user_pass = crypt($_POST['user_pass']);
$user_level = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_level']);

$encrypt = md5($user_pass);
$admin_query = "select * from admin_login where user_name='$user_name' AND user_pass='$user_pass' AND user_level='$user_level'";
```

Sorry i am kinda new to password hashing , in the whole time i saved my passwords as plain texts.

EDIT: When i echo the query here are the results
crypt = $1$vh4.Mq4.$YaABh9aqRKbKpACTDApWb1 ,select * from admin_login where user_name='testcr' AND user_pass='$1$vh4.Mq4.$YaABh9aqRKbKpACTDApWb1' AND user_level='a' ,the real password is "test" .

Comment: [Crypt](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.crypt.php) on php.net. Pretty self explanatory there.

Comment: I just came from there ,maybe i am too dumb to understand password hasing..

Comment: what does the hash in your database look like? And what is the point of setting `$encrypt`? You aren't using it. Also, echo out your query to see what it looks like and make sure it is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have choosen an extremely unsafe way to store the passwords (DES and MD5 hash without salting). You should think about using PHP's function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), to create a BCrypt hash.

For verification you will first have to get the hash from the database by username, afterwards you can verify the password with [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Directly verifying the hash with an SQL query is not possible because of the salt.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

If you are interested to read more about this topic, have a look at my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your SQL statement.

```
$admin_query = "select * from admin_login where user_name='$user_name' AND user_pass='$user_pass' AND user_level='$user_level'";

echo $admin_query;
```

Run the query in your SQL engine and see if you can spot the differences.

Comment: Ok i have run the queri in sql and it looks like this . crypt = $1$vh4.Mq4.$YaABh9aqRKbKpACTDApWb1 ,select * from admin_login where user_name='testcr' AND user_pass='testcr' AND user_level='a' ,the password that i inpute is testcr but in the database crypt does not match..

Comment: Edit your original post - I can't see anything on your comment

Comment: Done look in the post.